# Problem in separating the digits of an n digit number

Tags: c

In our computer programming class, we had to separate the digits of a 5 digit number and display them on the screen, I managed to do that but then we were asked what we would do if it was an n digit number. I managed to create a program that determined the number of digits in a number, then I thought I would add the code for the 5 digit number in this program and modify it, but the output shown is not proper.

Here is the code which produced the errored output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int entry, j, input1;
    input1 = entry;
    j = 1;

    printf("Enter the n digit number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &entry);

    for (j = 1; entry > 1; j++) {
        entry = entry / 10;
    }

    printf("The number is %d digit number\n", j);

    int n, t, i;
    i = 1;

    while (input1 > 0) {
        t = input1 / (int)pow(10, j - i);
        input1 = input1 % (int)pow(10,j - i);
        printf("%d   ", t);
        i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The loop wasn't running for the second part and the output was just the digit is an n digit number (that code was working), then I changed the code so the user would input the numbers again and then it worked, here's the code for the running part:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int entry, j;
    j = 1;

    printf("Enter the n digit number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &entry);

    for (j = 1; entry > 1; j++) {
        entry = entry / 10;
    }

    printf("The number is %d digit number\n", j);

    int input1, n, t, i;
    i = 1;

    printf("Enter the %d digit number again:\n", j);
    scanf("%d", &input1);

    while (input1 > 0) {
        t = input1 / (int)pow(10, j - i);
        input1 = input1 % (int)pow(10, j - i);
        printf("%d   ",t );
        i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This code works but I have to prompt the user to input the number again.

Comment: I recommend that you use an array, one element for each digit. Initialize the array to all zeros. Then use a loop to extract the *lowest* digit from the number, and put it into the first element in the array. Then get the second digit and put it in the second element. And so on, until you have all digits. Then find the first zero in the array, and print out the elements of the array in reverse. No need to use the floating point `pow` functions.

Comment: And in fact the `pow` function can introduce errors when used on integers, and should be used as `(int)round(pow(10, j - i))`. Better though, is to see that a "number" isn't necessarily an integer, and input it as a string – particularly with phone and card "numbers" which are very undesirable to store as an integer.

Comment: In the first program, when you do `input1 = entry;` what is the value of `entry`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah that was my error, i have to declare input11 variable after scanning it, now the problem has been solved

Comment: @WeatherVane oh okayy Thank youu, i am a little new to C coding, will try to think like that now

Comment: @Chris: I would not recommend reformatting a poster's code for readability unless it is completely unreadable. You may inadvertently conceal a problem by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &entry);
input1=entry; // assign value to 'input1' after input 'entry' is taken
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of why this solves the problem? What is wrong with the code the OP have? Please read or refresh on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My input from the user variable is entry, I had declared input1=entry before scanning for entry, that's why the code failed.